# get cannot access EntityBean error where remove javaEbean dependency

Tags: java, spring, jpa, playframework, hibernate-entitymanager

i have a Play application that integrated with Spring and Hibernate JPA.

When I remove a javaEbean dependency from my build.sbt file I receive

> cannot access EntityBean

This are my dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
jdbc,
javaJdbc,
javaCore,
filters,
//  javaEbean,
cache,
//  javaWs,
//  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.3.8.Final",
javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-   api"),
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.0.Final",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21",
"org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.1.5.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "4.1.5.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "4.1.5.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "4.1.5.RELEASE",
"org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "4.1.5.RELEASE"
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: i just comment it, i put my build.sbt file in above

Comment: No I said did you run `activator clean` in console after changing `build.sbt`?

Comment: @singhakash  thanks for your reply, that's right. please post a answer to i accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to clean after changing `build.sbt` so the new dependency are not loaded.
Try `activator clean` in console.